# The program cannot start because php7.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: php, apache, oracle11g, oci8

I am trying to deploy OCI8 with PHP7 and Apache 2.4.
The database does not reside in my local pc. It is on a different server with Oracle 11g Enterprise version and 64bit architecture as well.

I am unable to load oci8 on my local PC with the following settings

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension_dir = c:\php\ext
```

The *path* in system variables is properly updated with **c:\php;**

I have followed the instructions carefully https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html

I am using all versions with 64bit as my PC is running 64bit:

1. mod_fcgid
2. instantclient
3. php7
4. apache 2.4

**phpinfo()** shows perfectly on my browser but it does not show a table for oci8. I then run the command **php -m** in cmd to double check the status, but I get the following popup:

```
The program cannot start because php7.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.
```

And the cmd window shows the following error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_oci8_11g'
(tried: C:\php\ext\php_oci8_11g (The specified module could not be
found.), C:\php\ext\php_php_oci8_11g.dll (The specified module could 
not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it working with extension=oci8_12c instead. It turned out that even if the remote Oracle Database I am trying to connect with is of version 11g, the latest oci8 version supports 11g as well.
This worked: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html

Comment: As you found out , Oracle has client-server version interopability.  The PHP OCI8 binary needs to match the version of Oracle libraries on the 'client machine' aka the machine where PHP is installed.  These Oracle client libraries can connect to various different DB versions.  In summary, Oracle Client 18 and 12.2 can connect to Oracle Database 11.2 or greater. Oracle Client 12.1 can connect to Oracle Database 10.2 or greater. Oracle Client 11.2 can connect to Oracle Database 9.2 or greater.